# MailKit - How can bodybuilder help create a complex email body with many images interspersed with text?

Tags: mailkit

For example, what if you need to create an email body like this:
Text ...
Image ...
Text ...
Image ...
Text

Here is one of the examples that works for one text and one image:

```
var builder = new BodyBuilder ();
var pathImage = Path.Combine (Misc.GetPathOfExecutingAssembly (), "Image.png");
var image = builder.LinkedResources.Add (pathLogoFile);

image.ContentId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId ();
builder.HtmlBody = string.Format (@"<p>Hey!</p><img src=""cid:{0}"">", image.ContentId);

message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody ();
```

Can we do something like `builder.HtmlBody +=`  to just keep adding more and more texts and images?

Answer (score 1):

The BodyBuilder class is designed to constructing typically message structures, not the type of thing you are doing.

You will need to construct your message manually, not using BodyBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of trial/error/testing, I discovered that you can indeed keep adding text and images to the HtmlBody object, as my question speculated, by using builder.HtmlBody +=

In response to the increasingly widespread use of TLS instead of SSL, and therefore the need to abandon the use of Microsoft's obsolete SmtpClient component, I have developed a comprehensive emailing test component, in Visual Basic, using the wonderful MailKit from JStedfast.

As my question suggested, I wanted to give my users the ability to compose a handsome email body using text interspersed with images as needed. If any VB developers would like to benefit from this work, just let me know.

@jstedfast - I just saw your answer after posting this. For my production version, I need to add images from a blob field in a SQLServer table. I intend to use the manual method, as you stated, to do that. But for images I was loading into my sample program, I was able to make a fairly complex email body using src=file for each image, and adding them with builder.HtmlBody +=

Comment: The response to @jstedfast should be posted as a comment under their answer, not as a part of your answer.